# Generic lambda expression

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, async-await

I have problem: I can in no way known I call this method:

```
public static Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(
    Func<Task<TResult>> function
)
```

If you do not have a generic parameter that I know I can do this:

```
Task.Run( () => { Task.Delay(10000) });
```

Can you tell my how I can to this and why?

Regards!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please try to rephrase it.

Comment: If you're asking how/why `Task.Run` returns a `Task<T>`.. it's because it is inferred which overload you use based on the `Func` delegate you pass into it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't know how to call the generic and asynchronous method? TResult is a placeholder. You will need to replace TResult with an actual class when you use it. Also, it is *very* important that you remember to await the result.

```
var myResultVar = await Task.Run<MyResult> (() => MyFunctionWhichReturns() );

public MyResult MyFunctionWhichReturns()
{
   return new MyResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling another overload of the `Task.Run` method:

```
public static Task Run(Func<Task> function)
```

An overview of all overloads is [given in the linked MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run%60%601%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework).